# How to insert random quotes on empty pages

Tags: double-sided, book-design, random

I am working on putting a book together. there are several places where I have `empty` pages as a result of new chapters.  I would like to dress these pages up a bit by adding a quotation, but I would like more than one quotation in the book.

The method I am currently using in the `book` class is:

```
\usepackage{lmodern}
\newlength\longest
\makeatletter
\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside%
\ifodd\c@page\else
\vspace*{\fill}

\settowidth\longest{\itshape ``but there is a miraculous feeling.''}
\hfill
\begin{center}
\parbox{\longest}{%
\raggedright{\itshape%
``The pages are still blank,\\
but there is a miraculous feeling\\
of the words being there,\\
written in invisible ink\\
and clamoring to become visible.''\par\bigskip
}
\raggedleft\scshape{Vladimir Nabokov}\par%
}
\end{center}
\vspace{\fill}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi
}
\makeatother
```

I really like the result this gives for the quote and would prefer to find a way to have several, similarly formatted quotes in the document.

Comment: I'm not able to produce LaTeX code at the moment but the `memoir` class includes macros like `\cleartooddpage[text]` which, like `\cleardoublepage`, moves to the next odd page  but with `text` on the skipped page if it otherwise would be empty. Maybe you, or someone, would be able to use something like this.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion.  While I love the simplicity of this approach, the problem I see with it is it does not redefine the empty page.  As a result, I would only be able to apply quotes where I specified `\cleartooddpage[text]`and I would still have empty pages on chapter breaks, with `\listoftables`, `\listoffigures`, &c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution. Choose how to display the quotations, I simply centered them on the page.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{%
  \clearpage
  \if@twoside
    \ifodd\c@page
    \else
%      \hbox{}% % this was in the original
      \thispagestyle{empty}
      \nextquotation
      \newpage
    \fi
  \fi
}
\newcounter{quotationcount}
\newcounter{defquotationcount}
\newcommand{\nextquotation}{%
  \stepcounter{quotationcount}%
  \vspace*{\fill}
  \begin{center}
  \csname randomquotation\thequotationcount\endcsname\par
  \end{center}
  \vspace*{\fill}
}
\newcommand{\newquotation}[2]{%
  \stepcounter{defquotationcount}%
  \@namedef{randomquotation\thedefquotationcount}{%
    \begin{varwidth}{.75\textwidth}
    \itshape#2\par\vspace{1ex}
    \hspace*{\fill}{\normalfont#1}
    \end{varwidth}
  }
}
\makeatother

%% The following should better go in a file
%% named, say, randomquotations.tex
%% saying here \input{randomquotations}
\newquotation{Oscar Wilde}
 {
  Whenever people agree with me \\
  I always feel I must be wrong.
 }
\newquotation{George Eliot}
 {
  Blessed is the man who, having nothing to say, \\
  abstains from giving wordy evidence of the fact.
 }
\newquotation{Ogden Nash}
 {
  I think that I shall never see \\
  a billboard lovely as a tree. \\
  Perhaps, unless the billboards fall, \\
  I'll never see a tree at all.
 }
%% end of quotations, courtesy of http://www.quotationspage.com

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

\chapter{Title}
text
\chapter{Title}
text
\chapter{Title}
text

\backmatter

% just to get another quotation
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Using an external file makes it easier to add new quotations and shuffle them around.

[image]

You may want to add a check on the number of available quotations:

```
\newcommand{\nextquotation}{%
  \stepcounter{quotationcount}%
  \vspace*{\fill}
  \begin{center}
  \ifnum\value{quotationcount}>\value{defquotationcount}
    {\Huge Hey! You need another quotation!\par}
  \else
    \csname randomquotation\thequotationcount\endcsname\par
  \fi
  \end{center}
  \vspace*{\fill}
}
```

Quotations were taken from [The Quotations Page](http://www.quotationspage.com)

Comment: Thank you.  This was the type of answer that I had been hoping to find.  I especially like having the quotes in another file so that I can use this information in a style file and change the quotes as needed.  Is there a way to have the counter reset when the quotes reach their limit?

Comment: @ChristopherLHansen There is surely a way, but repeating the quotations is the last thing I'd do. Collecting a bunch of them is easier.

Answer (score 1):

How about defining your citation block with arguments, i.e. 
 instead of \cleardoublepage {...} use

```
\def\cleardoublepage#1#2{
\clearpage\if@twoside%
\ifodd\c@page\else
\vspace*{\fill}
\settowidth\longest{\itshape ``but there is a miraculous     feeling.''}
\hfill
\begin{center}
\parbox{\longest}{%
\raggedright{\itshape%
``%
#1''\par\bigskip
}
\raggedleft\scshape{#2}\par%
}
\end{center}
\vspace{\fill}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi
}
```

and then, whereever you like,

```
\cleardoublepage{A very nice \\ citation \\ for the next \\ beautiful chapter.}{anonymous}
```

using your quotes. 
Sure the longest line recoginition might mess up a bit ... is that a serious problem?

Comment: I like that I can keep the formatting and that implementation is simple.  The problem I see is that when `empty` pages are generated automatically (with commands such as `\chapter{}`, `\tableofcontents`, or `\tableoffigures`), I am unable to add a quote to them.